# scrapy outputs results into one row of csv

Tags: python, scrapy

this is similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20740272/scrapy-csv-output-having-all-results-in-single-row) but the answers didn't work for me. this is actually a follow up question from initial [csv output woes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26528794/scrapy-crawlspider-output/26537844#26537844). with dreyescat's help i was able to get my CrawlSpider to output to csv. however, now it will only print two columns (that correspond to my two fields) and one row (dumping all the results in the appropriate column). i recreated the example dreyescat gave me from hackernews and it works perfectly and that's what i'm trying to replicate.

Here's my code (which is pretty much copied from that hackernews example):

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from targets.items import TargetsItem

class MySpider(CrawlSpider):   
    name = 'reuters'
    allowed_domains = ['blogs.reuters.com']
    start_urls = [
        'http://blogs.reuters.com/us/'
    ]

    rules = (
        Rule(LinkExtractor(allow_domains=('blogs.reuters.com', )), callback='parse_item'),
    )

    def parse_item(self, response):
        item = TargetsItem()
        item['title'] = response.xpath('//h2/a/text()').extract()
        item['link'] = response.xpath('//h2/a/@href').extract()
        return item
```

The edited output from console looks like this:

`2014-10-24 13:04:04-0400 [reuters] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 http://blogs.reuters.com/hugo-dixon/>
{'link': [u'//blogs.reuters.com/hugo-dixon/2014/10/20/markets-right-to-worry-about-euro-zone/',
          u'//blogs.reuters.com/hugo-dixon/2014/10/13/italy-has-no-good-plan-b/',
          u'//blogs.reuters.com/hugo-dixon/2014/10/06/how-to-manage-a-corporate-crisis/',

'title': [u'Markets right to worry about euro zone',
          u'Italy has no good Plan B',
          u'How to manage a corporate crisis']}`

But I want it to look like the output from the example dreyescat gave me:

`2014-10-24 13:14:54-0400 [hackernews] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=8502433>
{'comment': [u"I get it - Java people want to work in Java.  However, this tool seems only targeted at the M in the MVC paradigm.  You still need to write your views and controllers in Objective-C.  Unless your app has a large number of very complex model objects, it's probably quicker to just retype your model classes in Objective-C. Of course if your app does have a lot of very complex model objects (as Google probably does) and you want to always have them in sync across platforms without having to retype anything then this makes a ton of sense. But for the majority of apps, it does not."],
'title': [u'Google j2objc, a Java to iOS Objective-C translation tool and runtime']}`

i suspect it has something to do with my xpath but at this point, i have very little idea what i'm doing wrong. hopefully, someone can help me out. much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your xpath seems to be targetting the  element of the homepage itself. But the code doesn't work exactly like that: let me try to explain.

```
rules = (
    Rule(LinkExtractor(allow_domains=('blogs.reuters.com', )), callback='parse_item'),
)
```

The above code block defines what kind of links are useful (to be processed further). The spider then picks up all the links in the above domain, and opens the page, and passes the individual page to `parse_item` function. So your xpath in the `parse_item` function should really be targetting at the page that opens when you click one of the `blogs.reuters.com/...` links.

In this case, the links in the homepage lead to individual articles. I just checked that the headline of the article can be captured by using the xpath `//h2/text()`.

So maybe you should change the `parse_item` function to look like this:

```
def parse_item(self, response):
    item = TargetsItem()
    item['title'] = response.xpath('//h2/text()').extract()
    item['link'] = response.xpath('<insert an xpath to obtain the link from the news post>').extract()
    return item
```

Remember, `parse_item` gets every link that's in the domain `blogs.reuters.com`. You've to write xpaths that understand the page at *every link*.

I couldn't find the link of the page in the page. you can maybe use the url in that case:

```
    item['link'] = response.url #or something. read the manual
```